# How to get Ring of Wizardry in PFS?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

[Ring of Wizardry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=462) is an Uncommon magic item.

How can I get it in Pathfinder Society? I tried searching for boons granting access on https://paizo.com/pathfindersociety/faq, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It's currently unavailable

Standard Uncommon options require access, usually from a feat, or a boon like Avid Collector or a chronicle boon. Neither currently exist for the Ring of Wizardry, so it's not usable in Pathfinder Society right now.

This table explains availability in Society play in greater detail https://paizo.com/pathfindersociety/characteroptions

Comment: I know how access works, where I need help is finding _which_ boon provides it. I update the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @András There are no boons that give it currently. That's what my answer says.

Comment: In general, contents of boons aren't published by Paizo any more, since you have to purchase the boon to see the actual text.